# AzureManagement Library create app service linking VsTs git

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-management-api

My code is hosted on Visual Studio Team Services repository however it is asking for public git repository. How can i achieve this?`WithPublicGitRepository`

```
try
{
    var app = await azure.WebApps.Define(appName)
        .WithRegion(newAppService.Region)
        .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
        .WithNewFreeAppServicePlan()
        .WithAppSettings(newAppService.AppSettings)
        .DefineSourceControl()
        .WithPublicGitRepository("VsTs git url")
        .WithBranch("master")
        .Attach()
        .CreateAsync();
    return app.HostNames.First();                
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: @Will updated code with correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Public git repository is not supported in Visual Studio Team Services, you can use another public git repository, such as GitHub.

You can import repository to GitHub: [Importing a repository with GitHub Importer](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer/)